# How to remove default blue background on treeview nodes c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a treeview but when I click on a node it displays a blue background.
Do you have a solution to remove this blue background ? I am using winform c#
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried modifying this property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.backcolor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: @Valuator hi  not yet

Comment: @Valuator i tried it, it works but before it shows the blue backgroundColor around the text of node

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.backcolor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the blue background color of a node that is selected by mouse click, set the `DrawMode` property of the tree view to `OwnerDrawText` and handle the node label drawing as shown:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        treeView.DrawNode += customDrawNode;
        treeView.AfterSelect += setTitleBarText;
    }
```

If the node is selected, custom draw the label. Non-selected nodes draw default.

```
    private void customDrawNode(object? sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is TreeView treeView)
        {
            if ((e.Node != null) && e.State.HasFlag(TreeNodeStates.Selected))
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(treeView.BackColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
                }
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(treeView.ForeColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, treeView.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
```

Verify selected node by setting main form text.

```
    private void setTitleBarText(object? sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        Text =
            treeView.SelectedNode == null ?
            "Main Form" :
            $"Main Form: {treeView.SelectedNode.Text}";
    }
}
```

[image: no-background selected node]